# HttpClient not found in elastic4s?

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I am getting below error while using HttpClient. Can you let me know how to use HttpClient exactly. I am new with elastic4s.
 I want to connect scala with ssl configured elasticsearch. I also want to know how I can pass SSL details with link such as keystore path, truststore path and user name , password.

```
scala> import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.{HttpClient, HttpResponse}
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.{HttpClient, HttpResponse}

scala> import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.ElasticDsl._
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.ElasticDsl._

scala> val client = HttpClient(ElasticsearchClientUri(uri))
<console>:39: error: not found: value HttpClient
       val client = HttpClient(ElasticsearchClientUri(uri))
```

Comment: HI,
Did you found any solution to pass truststore path and username ?

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClient` appears to be a trait in the codebase.You seem to be using the same as an object. You can check the implementation [Here](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/55ce039cd559262c721ace13cd9f3c116ca6761b/elastic4s-core/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/HttpClient.scala#L15). For your use case i think the better approach would be to use ElasticClient. Code would look something like this

```scala
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http._
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.{ElasticClient, ElasticDsl, ElasticsearchClientUri}
val client = elastic4s.ElasticClient(ElasticsearchClientUri(uri))
```

Comment: thank you so much, I have already tried it but didnt get any way to pass properties like certificate path and password of keystore etc. Can you please provide it and also I think there is one typo in your comment "ElasticClient" is part of com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http not com.sksamuel.elastic4s.

Comment: @Nakul- You have to use elastic4s-http dependency

Comment: @user1668782 Can you please share the code to pass truststore certificate path and password

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, i.e. in my setup I got errors (not found) when trying to use `HttpClient` (`elastic4s-core`,`elastic4s-http-streams` and `elastic4s-client-esjava` version 7.3.1 on scala 2.12.10).

The solution: you should be able to find and use `JavaClient`, an [implementation](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/master/elastic4s-testkit/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/testkit/DockerTests.scala) of HttpClient that wraps the Elasticsearch Java Rest Client.

An example of how to use the `JavaClient` can be found [here](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/master/elastic4s-testkit/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/testkit/DockerTests.scala).

Thus, your code should look like the following:

```
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.JavaClient
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.{ElasticClient, ElasticDsl, ElasticProperties}
...
val client = ElasticClient(JavaClient(ElasticProperties(uri)))
```